# Tensorflow installation error (ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, installation, python-3.7, nvidia-jetson-nano

`pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`I tried installing tensorflow in my virtual environment and kept on running into this error. I have the necessary prerequisites for pip3(pip 21.0.1) and python3(Python 3.7.9) version and cannot understand why this error is occurring. Any inputs to solve this error would be very much appreciated.

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wTDr.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

This line worked for me but then this error popped up while checking for the tensorflow version

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nvidia/projects/hand_gesture/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/nvidia/projects/hand_gesture/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/nvidia/projects/hand_gesture/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/nvidia/projects/hand_gesture/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[error terminal description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGhtx.png)